# Authentication for Virtuoso HTTP POST/PUT

Tags: security, http-post, rdf, virtuoso

I tried to execute an `INSERT` statement for an RDF triple in Virtuoso using its web-based SPARQL endpoint (http://localhost:8890/sparql/):

```
INSERT DATA
  { 
      GRAPH <http://my.graph> 
      { 
        <http://test.com/someid> <http://namespace.ref#someVar> 123
      } 
  }
```

but I got

> Virtuoso 42000 Error SR186:SECURITY: No permission to execute procedure DB.DBA.SPARQL_INSERT_DICT_CONTENT with user ID 107, group ID 107

I was able to run the same statement through my DB editor that uses a JDBC driver on port `1111`, using the `DBA` login.

The web interface/service insert was successful after I ran the following as a `DBA` through port `1111`:

```
grant execute on DB.DBA.SPARQL_INSERT_DICT_CONTENT to "SPARQL";
grant execute on DB.DBA.SPARQL_INSERT_DICT_CONTENT to SPARQL_UPDATE;
```

However, I would like to revoke those privileges from user `SPARQL`, which I understand is associated with the web interface, and send HTTP `POST`/`PUT`/`DELETE` requests with supplied user credentials using digest authentication. Is that possible and how? I went to [this page of the manual](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparql/#rdfsupportedprotocolendpointurisparqlauthex) but it was empty.

Comment: The manual is undergoing some restructuring. The section you wanted is [now here](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlprotocolendpoint/#rdfsupportedprotocolendpointurisparqlauthex) (the chapter is now split over multiple pages).

Comment: thanks.  if you would like to up your score (and increase the visibility of your product through search engines), consider posting a digest of that page as it pertains to my question in an answer.

Answer (score 6):

The OP's goal is discussed in [the new location of the manual page](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlprotocolendpoint/#rdfsupportedprotocolendpointurisparqlauthex) they originally tried to visit.  (More details are on the product site, than are reproduced below.)

> Virtuoso reserves the path `/sparql-auth/` for a SPARQL service supporting authenticated SPARUL (a/k/a SPARQL-Update). This endpoint allows specific SQL accounts to perform SPARUL over the SPARQL protocol. To be allowed to log in via SQL or ODBC and update physical triples, a user must be granted `SPARQL_UPDATE` privileges. To grant this role:
>
> 1. Go to the Virtuoso administration UI, i.e., `http://host:port/conductor`
> 2. Log in as user `dba`
> 3. Go to **System Admin** → **User Accounts** → **Users**
> 4. Click the **Edit** link
> 5. Set **User type** to **SQL/ODBC Logins and WebDAV**.
> 6. From the list of available **Account Roles**, select `SPARQL_UPDATE` and click the **`>>`** button to add it to the right-hand list.
> 7. Click the **Save** button.

Answer (score 0):

This procedure, which I picked up [here](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/181#issuecomment-91042748), worked for me:

Logged in as dba, under System Admin > User Accounts,

```
grant SPARQL_UPDATE to "SPARQL"
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the OP's wish to use "supplied user credentials using digest authentication", and simply opens the public endpoint to updates from anyone.